# How check if one column value from the Cursor is empty?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to insert value into my DB depends on the status of the values.

If **COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER** is **empty**, insert the data.

If **COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER** is **not empty**, update the data.

I use button so when the user click on it he get the following method comes:

```
public String putParameters(String parametersList, String exercise) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER, parametersList);
        cv.put(COLUMN_EXERCISE, exercise);

        String whereClause =  COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '"+ exercise+ "'";

        if(checkParameters(exercise) == false)
        {
            ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
            String i = "insert";
            return i;
        }   
        else
        {
            ourDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, whereClause, null);
            String u = "update";
            return u;
        }
    }
```

**checkParameters method code:**

```
public String getParameters(String exercise){

    String foo = "";

    String whereClause = COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '" +  exercise + "'";

    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER};

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, whereClause , null, null, null, null);

    int parameter = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER);


    try{
    c.moveToFirst();
    foo = c.getString(parameter);
    if (foo == null)
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception F)
    {
        foo = "bad";
        return foo;
    }
    return "";
    }   

    public boolean checkParameters(String exercise){


        String whereClause = COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '" +  exercise + "'";

        String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER};

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, whereClause , null, null, null, null);

        int parameter = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER);

        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.isNull(parameter))
            return false;
        return true;    
    }
```

My problem is that i never get **c.isNull(parameter) == false**. I always get "insert" message.
How can i check if **COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER** is empty? my code is correct?
Thank for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public boolean checkParameters(String exercise){


    String whereClause = COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '" +  exercise + "'";

    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER};

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, whereClause , null, null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.isAfterLast())
        return false; // no entry found for given exercise
    if(c.isNull(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER)))   // check for null value
        return false;
    if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER)).equals(""))  // check for empty string
        return false;
    return true;    
}
```

Edit: I think maybe what you want here is not to check whether the parameter field is empty, but if the entry for the given exercise exists or not. If the exercise exists in the DB, you need to update it, regardless of the value of the parameter, otherwise add a new entry. Right?

If so then use this code:

```
public boolean checkParameters(String exercise){

    String whereClause = COLUMN_EXERCISE + "= '" +  exercise + "'";

    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER};

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, whereClause , null, null, null, null);

    int parameter = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER);

    if (c.getCount() == 0)
        return false;
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.

the first code is not working =\

The second code is not good because exercise can be in the DB but with empty COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER column.

Comment: Second code should work. If its in the db and empty, update it. That will work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER will have a default value. Why don't you check the value by yourself？

```
 int parameter = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIELDS_PARAMETER);
 String value = c.getString(parameter);
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(value) {
    return false;
 }
 return true;
```

Comment: i tried and it wont work...
I changed my code so the user can only "update" and not to "insert" so it make it all easier.
Thank for helping :)